# PHP generated CSV file has 0 output as last character

Tags: php, csv

I am using PHP to retrieve data from a table and output it to a CSV file. The problem is though when I look at the contents of the generated file in Sublime it all looks fine, however if I open it in notepad++ instead I can see that there is a random 0 at the end of the file. This is causing problems because it causes excel to interpret the data in the last column wrong and display it incorrectly.

Here is my code:

```
$handle = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'export/soulmates.csv', 'w');

$columns = array('member_id', 'title', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'dob', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'citytown', 'county', 'postcode', 'marketing_opt_in', 'created');

fwrite($handle, '"'.implode('","', $columns).'"'.PHP_EOL);

$members = $this->wpdb->get_results("SELECT ".implode(', ', $columns)." FROM $this->table_name", ARRAY_N );

foreach($members as $member) {

    fputcsv($handle, $member);
}
fclose($handle);
```

The contents of `$members` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member_id] => smith12345
            [title] => Mr
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Smith
            [email] => johnsmith@gmail.com
            [dob] => 1988-01-01
            [address_1] => 1 Street
            [address_2] => Somewhere
            [citytown] => London
            [county] => London
            [postcode] => SY31AA
            [marketing_opt_in] => 1
            [created] => 2016-06-29 11:22:41
        )
)
```

Here is the output as viewed in sublime:

```
"member_id","title","first_name","last_name","email","dob","address_1","address_2","citytown","county","postcode","marketing_opt_in","created"
"smith12345","Mr","John","Smith","johnsmith@gmail.com","1988-01-01","1 Street","Somewhere","London","London","SY31AA","1","2016-06-29 11:22:41"
```

Here is the output as viewed in notepad++:

```
"member_id","title","first_name","last_name","email","dob","address_1","address_2","citytown","county","postcode","marketing_opt_in","created"
"smith12345","Mr","John","Smith","johnsmith@gmail.com","1988-01-01","1 Street","Somewhere","London","London","SY31AA","1","2016-06-29 11:22:41"
0
```

Notice there is an extra 0 at the end of the output for some reason.

Does anyone know how or why this 0 is being output?

Comment: No idea, but why not use fputcsv?

Comment: removing `PHP_EOL` might help

Comment: I've changed it to use fputcsv but still get the same problem

Comment: Could you update your question with the new code using fputcsv?

Comment: Could you also try adding the headers using fputcsv? Is the script finishing at the `fclose($handle)` line?